# Como acessar um módulo Cocoa Touch Framework no Playground Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

Criei um módulo Cocoa Touch Framework no **Xcode 6.0.1** com Classe implementada em Swift e consigo importa na minha View Controller e usá-la normalmente. O problema que o não consigo usar o mesmo código no Playground criado no mesmo projeto.

No **Playground** o modulo é reconhecido mas a classe contida nele não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha classe é declarada em JSON.swift assim:

```
public class JSON {
    // meu código Swift 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso no seu Playground do `Xcode 6.0.1`

```
import Foundation
let jsonObject: [AnyObject] = [
  ["name": "João", "age": 20],
  ["name": "Pedro", "age": 45],
]
func JSONStringify(jsonObj: AnyObject) -> String {
  var e: NSError?
  let jsonData: NSData! = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
    jsonObj,
    options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
    error: &e)
  if e != nil {
    return ""
  } else {
    return NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  }
}
let jsonString = JSONStringify(jsonObject)
println(jsonString)
```

Funciona no **Mavericks**

Desta forma funciona pois você está delegando o trabalho de serialização à [classe `NSJSONSerialization` da biblioteca padrão](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html)

Ou seja, seu código Swift é apenas um Wrapper.

A deserialização também pode ser feita de forma análoga.

Answer (score -1):

Por defeito as classes têm visibilidade `internal`. Apenas é necessário colocar a classe como pública e já ficas com o acesso.

```
public class Foo {
    public init() {
    }
}
```

Comment: a classe já está como publica. Veja a descrição da pergunta.